# Instantiating a generic class in dart

Tags: generics, dart

I've looked at the examples on stackoverflow using typedef, but it looks like it's mostly used for callbacks, so not sure if it's relevant for what I'm working on.
I'm implementing a class using generics that does RPC ...

```dart
abstract class Message {

  int created = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  Map map = new Map();

  Map toJson();
  void fromJson(String json){
    map = JSON.decode(json);
    this.created = map["created"];
  }

  String toString() {
    return JSON.encode(this);
  }

  Message(){
    map["created"] = created;
  }

}
```

___Request and ___Response both extends Message:

```dart
import 'Message.dart';

class TestResponse extends Message {

  String test;
  String message;

  Map toJson() {
    map["test"] = this.test;
    return map;
  }

  fromJson(String json) {
    super.fromJson(json);
    this.test = map["test"];
    this.message = map["message"];
  }

}
```

Now when I try to do a generic RPC class that hides all the boilerplate of sending and receiving messages, I need to create a new instance of the response class to send it back.
(I would have preferred to do RPC.submit, but that gives me an error saying static Static members cannot reference type parameters, so my other option here is to maybe abuse the constructor syntax, eg RPC.submit(json, uri).getResponse() ...)

```dart
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
import 'Message.dart';

class RPC<REQ extends Message, RES extends Message> {

  RES submit(REQ req, String uri){
    var client = new BrowserClient();
    var url = "http://localhost:9090/application-api" + uri;
    RES res = new RES(); // <----- can't do this
    client.post(url, body: req.toString()).then((response){
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      res.fromJson(response.body);

    });
    return res;  
  }

}
```

In my submit method, I can obviously pass in an instance of "RES res" and just use that, but I was hoping that it can be done inside the generic RPC without too much extra boilerplate, is that somehow possible in dart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems related to http://dartbug.com/10667

What I did in a similar situation was to create a static map which maps types to closurized constructors. I initialize the map with the message types and a closure for each which create a new instance of that type.
Then I look up the closure using the type argument and call the returned closure to get a new instance.

```
var factories = {
  'A': () => new A(),
  'B': () => new B(),
  'C': () => new C(),
};

...

var a = factories['A']();
```

You can integrate the factory into the class

```
class A {
  static A createNew() => new A();
}

var factories = {
  'A': A.createNew,
  'B': B.createNew,
  'C': C.createNew,
};
...
var a = factories['A']();
```

Comment: ok, so based on that bug report, it's not yet possible to do it. So for now, it seems the simplest way to get a one-liner RPC call is to do TestResponse res = new RPC().submit(req, new TestResponse(), "/test"); Closurized constructors sounds messy, but I can see other scenarios where that might be useful. Thanks Günter!

Comment: Can you post a simple code example of your explanation Günter?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer http://dartbug.com/10667 - That would be a cool feature. Any idea when this will be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a custom factory that generated responses as you need them and pass it to your RPC class. That seems pretty straight forward to me:

```
class RPC<REQ extends Message, RES extends Message> {

  static MessageFactory factory;

  RES submit(REQ req, String uri){
    // ...
    RES res = factory.createRES();
    // ..  
  }
}

abstract class MessageFactory {
   RES createRES();
}

class TestFactory extends MessageFactory {
  RES createRES() {
    return new TestResponse();
  }
}
```

// Somewhere in your code

```
RPC.factory = new TestFactory();
```